# I found an error in bash scripting of Linux which contained if condition with for loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..99}
do
    if [ i%2 != 0 ];
    then 
        echo $i
    fi
     
done
```

I want to print all odd numbers between 1 and 99, but it is printing all numbers between 1 and 99, not just the odds. Why isn't my simple `if` statement in the `for` loop filtering out the even numbers?

Comment: You can not write `for i in {1..99} do if [ i%2 != 0 ]; then echo $i fi` into a single line. You need either a line break or a semicolon for instance after `do` and before the `fi`.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: @mohdshariq There are some rules and recommendations about how to write questions and format code blocks. Those help readability and answering. Would you have a look and eventually adjust your question accordingly? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask The main things to be changed in your post are (please no all capitals) and format your code block.

Answer (score 4):

- Use [Arithmetic Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion)

```bash
for i in {1..99} 
do 
    if [ $((i%2)) != 0 ]
        then 
            echo $i 
        fi
done
```

### Better Solution

- From [@user1934428](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1934428/user1934428), [@tshiono](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8572380/tshiono) & [@Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton)  comments

```bash
for i in {1..99} 
do 
    if  ((i%2 != 0)) 
        then 
            echo "$i" 
        fi
done
```

Comment: This could be written simpler as `if (( i%2 != 0 ))`

Comment: Better to say `if (( i % 2 != 0 ))` or just `if (( i % 2 ))`.

Comment: `printf %s\\n {1..99..2}` or `i=-1;while(((i+=2)<=99))do echo $i;done`

Comment: Always quote your variables - use `echo "$i"`, not `echo $i`. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and http://shellcheck.net is your friend.

Answer (score 3):

The `{start..end}` construct has a 3rd argument of `increment` (default is +1): `{start..end..increment}`.

For printing odd values you provide the start and ending values with an increment of +2, eg:

```
for i in {1..99..2}; do echo "$i"; done
```

Or a shortened version if the sole purpose is to print the values to stdout:

```
printf "%s\n" {1..99..2}
```

Both of these generate:

```
1
3
5
7
... removed for brevity
93
95
97
99
```

---

Keep in mind that the series of values must first be generated and saved in memory.  In this case the generation and storage of 50 values is insignificant, but if you were to generate a series of numbers in the (100's of) millions then you'd see a large spike in cpu and memory usage just to generate/store those numbers.

For large series of numbers it is faster and more memory efficient to use something like:

```
for ((i=1;i<=99;i+=2))
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

**NOTE:** `i+=2` could be replaced with `i=i+2` to obtain the same outcome

This approach requires memory for just one value (the current value of the variable `i`) and requires a (relatively) insignificant amount of cpu to increment the variable on each pass through the loop.

This also generates:

```
1
3
5
7
... removed for brevity
93
95
97
99
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the *string* `i%2` is never identical to `0`, so your test always succeeds.

It appears that you wanted an arithmetic test:

```
if ((i%2 != 0))
```